# I installed an incompatible kernel with CyanogenMod - what do I do?

Tags: cyanogenmod, kernel

I installed Faux kernel on my Nexus 5 with CyanogenMod 11. I forgot about CM's special kernel setup when installing Faux - how do I uninstall, or wipe my phone to reinstall CyanogenMod?

I use ClockworkMod Recovery and know ADB

Comment: Post your "Resolved bit" as an answer, it's okay to answer your own questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved: Using this (http://android-revolution-hd.blogspot.ca/2013/12/how-to-copy-rom-zip.html) Then flashing the zip uploaded to the device. Note: If your cellular stops working or glitches out re-flash the stock radio (http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2513701) Or completely re-flash stock then you are free to continue ROMing!

Comment: And it would be good to accept it, but now you can do that after 24 hour. :P

Answer (score 0):

Nexus 5 is pretty easy to correct that issue

Just find a working CM Kernel...
This ones kinda nice: http://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/development/kernel-bum-5-t2774572

1. Boot to Recovery.
2. "adb push [your new kernel file here.zip] /sdcard/ 
   then wait...
3. Flash the new kernel.
4. Zap the dalvik cache.
5. As they say "profit"...